# Why can I compile it, when I am missing the last level directory in the package?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Why can I compile and run it, when I am missing the last level directory in the package?

I am learning springboot in recent days. When I run my code, it compiles and can be accessed in the browser. But, I found that my package path was not written completely.

[image]

as you saw, the `package` must be `com.test.forfree.controller`, but in my code, it's `com.test.forfree`:

```
package com.test.forfree;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Hello Boot 2.10!";
    }
}
```

I use `mvn spring-boot:run`, to run this project, it work's:

[image]

Then I change the `package` statement to `com.test.forfree.controller`:

```
package com.test.forfree.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Hello Boot 2.10!";
    }
}
```

It can still compile successfully and run. Why?

Comment: Please avoid using information that could be represented as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment of directories and package names is generally a good idea for source code, but it's not strictly required. Depending on how exactly you compile your code the tools might complain about it, warn you and still compile it or just silently compile your code.

The place where the directory structure **must** match the package structure is for the class files (either directly on disk of in jar files).

If you check the content of your `target` directory, you will notice that the `.class` files are all in the "proper" directories, even if the originating source files aren't.